# Loop through and display results in PHP from SELECT WHERE in SQL

Tags: php, sql, loops, echo

I have right now only 1 table, which contains people's names and addresses, and I wish to display data from the records where their country is GB.

I currently have the following code which I'm stumped doesn't work:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imported_orders WHERE ShipCountry='GB'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
        {
            echo "<br><b>Current Order ".$row['ID']."</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Date Purchased: </b>".$row['PurchaseDate']."<br>";
            echo "<b>Buyer Details</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Name : </b>".$row['BuyerName']."<br><b> Phone Number: </b>".$row['BuyerPhoneNumber']."<br><b> Email: </b>".$row['BuyerEmail']."<br>";
            echo "<b>Delivery Address</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Address Line 1 : </b>".$row['ShipAddress1']."<br><b> Address Line 2: </b>".$row['ShipAddress2']."<br><b> Address Line 3: </b>".$row['ShipAddress3']."<br><b>Country: </b>".$row['ShipCountry'];
        }
?>
```

It is in a file on its own right now so there is not other code to interfere with it.

All this code does is output the data from 1 record to screen, this being the data from the *last record which has GB as the country. If I change it to "IE" it will echo nothing, even though there are records with IE as the country.

I have also tried doing the WHERE SQL in PHP using an IF to check the value of the country, this gives the results as the above code.

EDIT: I tried it with:

```
WHERE ShipCountry like '%GB%'
```

and this works, as apparently 'GB' and 'IE' etc has a space after it, even though I imported the data to the table from a file using tab deliberated, so I'm not sure why there was a blank space imported after it.

Thanks for any help -Tom

Comment: Your MySQL-Query looks right to me. Did you try to execute it in PHPMyAdmin? If so, what was the result?

Comment: By the way: [mysql_* is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php). Please update your code for security reasons.

Comment: Is there any problem with db connection in your code?..Check whether it is connected or not..

Comment: Post the table structure

Comment: @Jenz I've tried the connection with or die and it connects fine, it out puts the first record it just doesn't seem to loop.

Comment: @Chris Good thinking, I just ran it and it only displays the same single record like when I view it through PHP, and it is the last record. So it is looping or just skipping through them all to the end.

Comment: Time to show us your table structure :)

Comment: The code doesn't seem to have any error. Are you sure that the query returns multiple records, I mean have records with ShipCountry='GB'?

Comment: @Chris is there a proper way to do this? I'm still very new to SQL and phpmyadmin, its a pretty big table with 24 columns some are dates some int, majority VARCHAR, the PK is an auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code as below to see if you get more than one result. 
If yes: then your ShipCountry does not have anything along with 'IE'

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imported_orders limit 30");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
        {
            echo "<br><b>Current Order ".$row['ID']."</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Date Purchased: </b>".$row['PurchaseDate']."<br>";
            echo "<b>Buyer Details</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Name : </b>".$row['BuyerName']."<br><b> Phone Number: </b>".$row['BuyerPhoneNumber']."<br><b> Email: </b>".$row['BuyerEmail']."<br>";
            echo "<b>Delivery Address</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Address Line 1 : </b>".$row['ShipAddress1']."<br><b> Address Line 2: </b>".$row['ShipAddress2']."<br><b> Address Line 3: </b>".$row['ShipAddress3']."<br><b>Country: </b>".$row['ShipCountry'];
        }
?>
```